# Adding blank line spaces before and after pattern 'string' match

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am trying to add 5 blank line spaces in a text file (text.txt) before and after string pattern matches. I used the following to get spaces after the 'string' match which worked for me-

```
sed '/string/{G;G;G;G;G;}' text.txt
```

I want to apply the same sed command to obtain 5 blank lines before the 'string' Here I don't want spaces, but rather blank lines before and after them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `sed -e '/string/{ s/^/\n\n\n\n\n/; s/$/\n\n\n\n\n/ }' text.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/(^.*)(string)(.*$)/\1\n\n\n\n\n\2\n\n\n\n\n\3/' text.txt
```

Use -r or -E to allow regular expressions, split likes into three sections and then substitute the line for the first section, 5 new lines, the second section, 5 new lines and then finally the third section.

Comment: Suppose if I want to do it with many strings for 'string 1' ' string 2' and 'string 3' in the same text.txt. How can i modify?

Comment: Use `-r` or `-E` to enable EREs (Extended Regular Expressions).  For maximum portability, per POSIX, use `-E`.

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/string1\|string2\|string3/\n\n\n\n\n&\n\n\n\n\n/g' file` would work for GNU sed?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/string/\n\n\n\n\n$&\n\n\n\n\n/' text.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` : change `PATTERN` to `REPLACEMENT`.
`$&` : matched pattern.
`\n` : newline character.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 1):

For a single string match:

```
$ sed -e '/string/{ s/^/\n\n\n\n\n/; s/$/\n\n\n\n\n/ }' text.txt
```

For multiple strings, assuming same requirements:

```
$ sed -E '/(string1|string2|string3)/{ s/^/\n\n\n\n\n/; s/$/\n\n\n\n\n/ }' text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/string/{G;s/\(string\)\(.*\)\(.\)/\3\3\3\3\3\1\3\3\3\3\3\2/}' file
```

Match on `string`, append an empty line, pattern match using the newline to separate the match by 5 lines either side.

Answer (score 0):

And an `awk` version:

```
awk '{if(/string1|string2|.../){printf "\n\n\n\n\n%s\n\n\n\n\n",$0}else{print}}' file
```